# heroku commands and push giving me 'CLI is deprecated. Please reinstall' error

Tags: git, heroku, version-control, bitbucket, push

I have had no problem pushing to heroku, but now whenever I write a command such as:

```
heroku create
heroku open

git push heroku master
```

It gives me this error:

```
$  heroku open
 ▸    heroku-cli: This CLI is deprecated. Please reinstall from
 ▸    https://cli.heroku.com
```

What should I do to stop this?

I have ran heroku for sites that have given me no problem before but now the error is showing. 
I am using the same devise and the authentication details have not changed.
I also restarted the computer (it's a mac).

Comment: What version of Heroku are you running?

Comment: $ heroku --version
 ▸    heroku-cli: This CLI is deprecated. Please reinstall from
 ▸    https://cli.heroku.com
heroku-toolbelt/3.43.12 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
heroku-cli/6.10.9-b8f5c7d (darwin-x64) node-v7.10.0
 ▸    no plugins installed
You have no installed plugins.

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same issue. I have installed and uninstalled Heroku CLI from the command line several times (using Heroku's instructions) and continue to get it.

Comment: I've got the same problem.

Comment: Same problem here! Happened after the automatic Heroku CLI update.

Comment: Same issue.ubuntu@box216:~$  heroku apps --all
 ▸    heroku-cli: This CLI is deprecated. Please reinstall from https://cli.heroku.com
 ▸    Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
 !    error getting commands pid 20872 exit 1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Upgrade your heroku cli with homebrew as follows:

```
brew upgrade heroku
```

If you see `Error: heroku not installed` message, install it again:
`brew install heroku`.
You can also see the following output:

```
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/heroku
Target /usr/local/bin/heroku
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/heroku'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite heroku

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run heroku

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/heroku -> /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
```

In this case just follow the instructions and run:
`brew link --overwrite heroku`

Test if you still have the deprecation message, for ex.:
`heroku logs`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Solved updating heroku from brew and then running `brew link --overwrite heroku`

Comment: This works for my on  macos. But no idea how to do it on ubuntu, which is used by circleci. I have tried the apt-get and manual install, no success, just same error, as TS described.

Comment: i did the same after i asked the question, i followed the link in the error [link]cli.heroku.com [link] and used brew to install and update heroku.. it all works now but i still get the same warning messages.

so i ran your solution after i ran brew install.. and it seems to be working fine again without any errors.. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

For Windows users.

After installing an updated version of the cli I ended up with a 32 bit version in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku` (called the Heroku Toolbelt - the old one), and a 64 bit version in 'C:\Program Files\Heroku' (called the Heroku CLI - the new one). Both were in my `%PATH%` environment variable, but the older one took precedence as it was higher up.

Resolution is either:

1. Remove `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku` from the system environment variables

or

2. Uninstall the heroku toolbelt

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error and I fixed it with:

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade heroku
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: brew update heroku
Error: This command updates brew itself, and does not take formula names.
Use 'brew upgrade <formula>'.

i get this when i do what you say

Answer (score 2):

Just because you have the CLI installed does not mean when you run `heroku` that it is running the newly installed version. First, run `which heroku` to see where the heroku binary is that you're running. If it's not `/usr/local/bin/heroku` you'll need to either delete that file, or edit your PATH environment variable so `/usr/local/bin` takes precedence.

If it is `/usr/local/bin/heroku` likely you need to update the symlink. If you run `brew doctor` it will tell you if the symlinks are not set correctly.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Take note; you may have /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku. This must be deleted to that /usr/local/bin/heroku takes precedence

Answer (score 1):

All the solutions above didn't work for me as my `brew` wasn't compatible with OS X 10.2

If you get the following warning:

```
Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
```

Here is what worked for me:

Try to update brew:

```
brew update
```

You may encounter with a new permission issue as I did:

```
Error: /usr/local must be writable!
```

If so, simply run the following:

```
sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local
brew update
```

Now, when you have an updated `brew` that is compatible with Mac OS 10.2, all you need to do is to update `heroku`

you can just upgrade it:

```
brew upgrade heroku
```

Or uninstall and then install it:

```
brew uninstall heroku
rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku ~/.config/heroku ~/.cache/heroku
brew install heroku
```

To test your updated Heroku just try

```
heroku logs
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had originally installed heroku as a ruby gem, so I had to run:

```
$ gem uninstall heroku
```

Then reinstall the new version from Homebrew

```
$ brew install heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

I just asked the Heroku support and they advised me to reinstall Heroku-cli via homebrew and it worked like a charm.

Cheers